# Git signoff commit without changing author

Tags: git

For the project I work on, we use `--signoff` as the way to approve each other's commits. I know that this isn't the way most projects work, but the model we have is that someone writes a patch, someone else reviews it and `--signoff`'s it, and the original author pushes it into the mainline.

The problem we have is that the original author of the commit goes away after the signoff. When someone does the command to signoff, it usually looks something like this:

```
git commit --amend --signoff
```

This of course updates the author field in addition to appending the signoff at the end of the commit message.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing without actually changing the author field? The only option I can see is to go look at the original author field and pass that in with:

```
--author "John Smith <john.smith@somewhere.com>"
```

which seems rather clunky and a pain to do every time you want to signoff a commit.

**Update:**

By popular demand, my `.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = Wesley Bland
    email = ---@---.---

[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
    ui = auto

[color "status"]
    added = green
    changed = red
    untracked = magenta

[core]
    whitespace = trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-tab
    abbrev = 8
    excludesfile = /Users/wbland/.gitignore_global

[alias]
    graph = log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline

[push]
    default = simple
```

Comment: Are you using any commit triggers?

Comment: The only hooks I see in the `.git/hooks/` directory are the samples that are set up in every repo.

Comment: I know this may sound silly, but when you run `git commit`, can you verify (e.g., with `strace` or `truss`) that it's actually running the `git-commit` script from an un-customized git installation?

Comment: Hmm...looks like I might have done something weird like that. I do have two installations (default Apple and Homebrew) and when I specify the other one, the problem doesn't come up. I'll figure it out from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git commit` (including `git commit --ammed --signoff`), by default, does **not** change the author of a commit.
In fact, in order to do so, you'd need to explicitly specify you'd like to do so:

```
git commit --amend --signoff --reset-author
```

Comment: Hmm. Then we must all have something in our config that causes it to do so because this happens to everyone who is committing.

Comment: Can you share you `.git/config` ?

Comment: Sure, I just added it.